# What is the real vehicle used as The Highwayman's truck?

Tags: the-highwayman

Can anyone tell me what the real vehicle used as *The Highwayman*'s truck is? Is it actually a real helicopter fixed into a truck?

[image]

Comment: What does "serious as highway mans truck" mean? Do you mean **series**?

Comment: Please don't repeat your entire question just to get more characters into the question text. And please don't post comments as answers to your question, you already have the privilege to comment on posts.

Comment: It looks like an impossible vehicle... or at least a sneakily deceptive prop. To work "in-universe", the helicopter nose would have to be fixed relative to the trailer, but it appears that it is actually part of the tractor and there is disguised articulation aligned over the fifth wheel. I suspect it was never filmed (or at least footage edited out) negotiating a corner where tractor and trailer would have to articulate otherwise it would reveal the deception. It looks like the helicopter nose might have come from a real helicopter, but only the first few feet of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It was a [1980 Kenworth cabover](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=1980%20Kenworth%20cabover&client=ubuntu&hs=LBb&channel=fs&biw=1084&bih=533&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4rPT5-prPAhUU24MKHYD8DOwQ_AUICCgB) with an 8V92T diesel which was later converted into the futuristic truck.

As [this](https://blog.hemmings.com/index.php/2009/09/18/can-you-believe-it-you-could-own-the-truck-from-tvs-the-highwayman/) news article says:

> Though it looks like a Luigi Colani creation, the truck actually
>   started out as a 1980 Kenworth cab-over with an 8V92T diesel before it
>   was converted, at a cost of $287,000, into the “futuristic” (the
>   series was set in 1992) truck used in the series. Jon Ward Motor
>   Sports of Alpine, Texas, which claims to have built the truck for the
>   series, apparently held on to the truck after the series ended and
>   kept the futuristic look, but began to convert it into a motor home,
>   complete with stacked washer and dryer, on-demand hot water and room
>   for a fireplace.

From the looks of that actual truck in real life and of the helicopter scene, I don't think it is a real helicopter. The front end is build to look like a helicopter along with the nose. CGI is used for the actual launch scene of the helicopter followed by an actual/CGI helicopter when it actually flies.

Also as per [this](http://www.retrojunk.com/article/show/770/80s-supervehicles) comment:

> For the inside shots of the cab, parts of KITT’s dashboard were reused

and [this](http://www.crazyabouttv.com/highwayman.html)

> In fact, some of the dashboard on the Highwayman's truck is salvage
>   from "K.I.T.T.", the artifically intelligent car on "Knight Rider".

it is evident that the insides of the cockpit/cab were not of a real helicopter.

Comment: It would not have been CGI, not in the late 1980s. It would all be practical effects - exteriors and interiors. The launch sequence (hinged panels, elevator, rotor deployment) appears to be all miniatures. Where the helicopter flies away, it looks like an optical effect using footage of a real helicopter combined with a truck miniature in foreground matte.